# Shared Element Transition between two Visible Fragments in a Tablet (Product List and Cart)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I Have two Fragments inflated on an Activity (in a Tablet),

1. A Product Grid View (A Recycler View which loads a grid from
   cursor) which contains an Imageview displaying product image.
2. A Cart view which contains the list of selected Products with product
   images in each list item.

I need to apply Shared Element Transition between the Product Image in the product grid and the image in the cart list.

So far I can see examples for implementing Shared Element Transition between two activities or two fragments where the second activity or fragment is newly inflated. But I have both the fragments inflated beforehand.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance. I couldn't find any such queries so asking a new question. Please redirect me if similar questions have been asked before.

Comment: What you want is [scene](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html) animation.

Comment: Take a look at "Shared Elements with Fragments" [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/).

Comment: @Cheticamp There are two scenarios in the link you shared. 1) where you open a new activity. 2) where you open a new fragment. But my case is, I will have 2 fragments in open state simultaneously. I need to make the animation for an image from one fragment to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Shared elements for Fragments can only be used when one Fragment is disappearing and another one is appearing. (As in [FragmentTransaction#replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))).

If you're not planning to move one of the Fragments out of the screen you'd have to layout the fragments yourself and while making one of them visible moving the elements around using [TransitionManager#beginDelayedTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.support.transition.Transition)).